# Cannot set hostname for ESP8266

Tags: dns, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, mdns

I am facing a problem, as setting host name for my ESP8266 is not working. Even though when I'm trying to connect through default host name "ESP_xxxx", it's not working.

Actually when I upload my code with my mobile hotspot SSID and password then it's working fine, but as soon as I gave the SSID and password of my router then it's not working.

Here's my code (setup part):

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "xxxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxx";

int ledPin = 13; // GPIO13
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.hostname("xyz");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");
  Serial.println(WiFi.hostname());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

//
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "WiFiManager.h"          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager

void configModeCallback (WiFiManager *myWiFiManager)
{
  Serial.println("Entered config mode");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  Serial.println(myWiFiManager->getConfigPortalSSID());
}

  // 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  WiFi.hostname("myhostname");
  //
  //wifiManager.resetSettings();

  //
  //
  wifiManager.setAPCallback(configModeCallback);
  if (!wifiManager.autoConnect("myhostname"))
  {
    Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
  // reset 
    ESP.reset();
    delay(1000);
  }
  //
  Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");

}

void loop()
{
  // 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this issue and below is the code which works for me.

```
WiFi.disconnect(true);
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
WiFi.setHostname(device);`
```

Also came across below code, with this line the module is not receiving any IP. Hence deleted it.

```
WiFi.config(INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE);
```

Running on Arduino 1.8.15 and esp8266 board version 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using mDNS instead.
Include the mDNS library

```
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
```

Then in the setup after you connected to WiFi, start mDNS like this.

```
if (!MDNS.begin("your-desired-hostname")) {
    Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");
}
```